# Python append 1 to list if condition exist and 0 to all other lists

Tags: python, if-statement

I have 3 lists:

```
a_exist = []
b_exist = []
c_exist = []
```

i am looping through a main list of strings:

```
l = ['a', 'b']

for item in l:

    if 'a' in item:

        a_exist.append(1)
        b_exist.append(0)
        c_exist.append(0)

    else:

        a_exist.append(0)
        b_exist.append(0)
        c_exist.append(0)

    if 'b' in item:

        b_exist.append(1)
        a_exist.append(0)
        c_exist.append(0)

    else:

        b_exist.append(0)
        a_exist.append(0)
        c_exist.append(0)
```

What i am trying to get:

```
a_exist = [1,0]
b_exist = [0,1]
c_exist = [0,0]
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You have five lists, but there are only three of them?

Comment: It looks a littel like you are trying to create dummies - you can try `get_dummies` from pandas or scikitlearns `OneHotEncoder`

Comment: Why don't you like what you wrote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternate take on this, your problem sounds like it would likely be better suited for a dictionary of lists. This makes it easy to extend (e.g., if you want to detect other characters, you just add them to the initial list `checks` below) without having to add a new `_exist` list each time.

```
In [7]: checks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

In [8]: l = ['a', 'b', 'ae', 'bcd']

In [9]: ret = {k: [int(k in v) for v in l] for k in checks}

In [10]: ret
Out[10]:
{'a': [1, 0, 1, 0],
 'b': [0, 1, 0, 1],
 'c': [0, 0, 0, 1],
 'd': [0, 0, 0, 1],
 'e': [0, 0, 1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
l = ['a', 'b']
a_exist = [1 if 'a' in i else 0 for i in l]
c_exist = [1 if 'b' in i else 0 for i in l]
b_exist = [1 if 'c' in i else 0 for i in l]
print(a_exist, b_exist, c_exist, sep='\n')
```

out:

```
[1, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 0]
```

Just combine the **list comprehension** and **conditional assignment**.
First loop through `l` and get each value, than check if the value match the condition, if the value match, return 1, else return 0